# Drush 7 bootstraps DB apparently without error, but still needs higher level

Tags: 7, drush

This is a Drupal 7 multi-site (subdirectory based with symlinks) I've migrated to a new server. (Perhaps worth mentioning Drush doesn't work on the old server either).  The websites don't have any obvious problems.

Bootstrapping appears to reach level 5 without any error. 
Debian 9.4, PHP 5.6. I've checked the [PHP.ini requirements](http://docs.drush.org/en/7.x/configure/#configuring-phpini) and I've definitely got the mysql PDO driver.

I *originally* installed Drush 7.x via Ansible (geerlingguy.drush role). I've now switched to Drush 8, installed manually (downloading Drush.phar from GitHub):

drush status (domains redacted):

(Note - if I use `drush status --uri=example.com/subsite1` or 
`drush status --uri=example.com/subsite2`, then the 'Drupal Settings File' and 'Site path' lines, plus database name etc. are updated accordingly, so the right settings.php file is being read and there doesn't appear to be a problem switching between sites.)

```
 Drupal version         :  7.58                       
 Site URI               :  http://default             
 Database driver        :  mysql                      
 Database hostname      :  localhost                  
 Database port          :  3306                       
 Database username      :  redacted            
 Database name          :  umbrella                   
 PHP configuration      :  /etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini   
 PHP OS                 :  Linux                      
 Drush script           :  /usr/local/bin/drush       
 Drush version          :  8.1.16                     
 Drush temp directory   :  /tmp                       
 Drush configuration    :                             
 Drush alias files      :                             
 Drupal root            :  /var/www/example/htdocs   
 Drupal Settings File   :  sites/default/settings.php 
 Site path              :  sites/default
```

Note for others: if Drush can't ever find the settings file, it'll display:

```
Drupal Settings File   :  MISSING
```

drush up --debug

```
Phar detected. Proceeding to drush_main().
Cache HIT cid: 8.1.16-commandfiles-0-dbfc5eac52981945177b460bd5c08987 [0.01 sec, 3.45 MB]                                                                                                                                                                     [debug]
Bootstrap to phase 0. [0.14 sec, 9.3 MB]                                                                                                                                                                                                                  [bootstrap]
Bootstrap to phase 6. [0.14 sec, 9.31 MB]                                                                                                                                                                                                                 [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_root() [0.14 sec, 9.69 MB]                                                                                                                                                                                       [bootstrap]
Initialized Drupal 7.58 root directory at /var/www/example/htdocs [0.14 sec, 9.69 MB]                                                                                                                                                                    [bootstrap]
Find command files for phase 1 (max=6) [0.15 sec, 7.3 MB]                                                                                                                                                                                                     [debug]
Cache HIT cid: 8.1.16-commandfiles-1-3f59809f319dc8415f75a4fe9a39c2e1 [0.15 sec, 7.3 MB]                                                                                                                                                                      [debug]
Cache HIT cid: 8.1.16-annotationfiles-1-f59a1308e828ee8afb57dc2e531b4a8b [0.15 sec, 7.3 MB]                                                                                                                                                                   [debug]
Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_site() [0.18 sec, 7.33 MB]                                                                                                                                                                                       [bootstrap]
Initialized Drupal site default at sites/default [0.18 sec, 7.33 MB]                                                                                                                                                                                      [bootstrap]
Find command files for phase 2 (max=6) [0.18 sec, 7.33 MB]                                                                                                                                                                                                    [debug]
Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_configuration() [0.18 sec, 7.33 MB]                                                                                                                                                                              [bootstrap]
Find command files for phase 3 (max=6) [0.19 sec, 7.36 MB]                                                                                                                                                                                                    [debug]
sql-query: SELECT 1; [0.19 sec, 7.48 MB]                                                                                                                                                                                                                     [notice]
Executing: mysql --defaults-extra-file=/tmp/drush_R3Phpd --database=umbrella --host=localhost --port=3306 --silent  < /tmp/drush_T5CkBa
  1
sql-query: SHOW TABLES; [0.2 sec, 7.48 MB]                                                                                                                                                                                                                   [notice]
Executing: mysql --defaults-extra-file=/tmp/drush_XA8Y3i --database=umbrella --host=localhost --port=3306 --silent  < /tmp/drush_lIZBeg
  actions
  apachesolr_environment
  apachesolr_environment_variable
  apachesolr_index_bundles
  apachesolr_index_entities
  apachesolr_index_entities_node

    [... long list of tables ...]

  webform_emails
  webform_last_download
  webform_localization
  webform_roles
  webform_submissions
  webform_submitted_data
  wysiwyg
  wysiwyg_user
Bootstrap to phase 1. [0.22 sec, 7.57 MB]                                                                                                                                                                                                                 [bootstrap]
Bootstrap to phase 6. [0.26 sec, 9.96 MB]                                                                                                                                                                                                                 [bootstrap]
Bootstrap to phase 5. [0.26 sec, 9.96 MB]                                                                                                                                                                                                                 [bootstrap]
Command pm-update needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will need to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment to run this command. [0.26 sec, 9.97 MB]                                                                                [error]
The drush command 'up' could not be executed. [0.26 sec, 9.97 MB]
```

If it's apparently connecting to the DB OK, what else should I be checking?

(Thanks.)

Comment: Hi! I notice that you are using Drush 7.4-dev. That makes it very hard to help you. I strongly recommend upgrading to Drush 8 - http://docs.drush.org/en/8.x/install/ - and then report the same output as above.

Comment: @hansfn Hi - thanks, I managed to misread the system requirements; assumed I could only use Drush 7 on Drupal 7 sites… downloaded now - via standard phar file rather than anything fancy in Ansible - and output updated - (same outcome).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by using database prefixes to share user/permission tables between multiple sites (turns out Drush has never really supported that).

There are a number of stages in the database bootstrapping phase. Although `drush_valid_db_credentials()` succeeds (and hence you can use `drush sql-` commands without issue), `bootstrap_drupal_database_has_table()` subsequently fails, because it's trying to look for a table named like this - "database.table" among a list of tables without any database prefixes.

That list of tables shown in my debug output is actually as part of that test, and the phase fails immediately, it's just not visible in the debug info.

These bootstrap messages…

```
Bootstrap to phase 1. [0.22 sec, 7.57 MB]                                                                                                                                                                              
Bootstrap to phase 6. [0.26 sec, 9.96 MB]
Bootstrap to phase 5. [0.26 sec, 9.96 MB]
```

…only refer to the **start** of the process - they're not telling you it was completed successfully.  In fact what's happening is more like this (with extra debugging added):

```
Bootstrap to phase 1. [0.85 sec, 8.77 MB]
result for 0 = 1
result for 1 = 1
Bootstrap to phase 6. [0.92 sec, 11.11 MB]
result for 0 = 1
result for 1 = 1
result for 2 = 1
result for 3 = 1
fail for 4
Bootstrap to phase 5. [0.92 sec, 11.11 MB]
result for 0 = 1
result for 1 = 1
result for 2 = 1
result for 3 = 1
fail for 4
```

*result = 1 indicates success. Note each phase only actually runs once  - the results are cached in a static array to speed things up.*

**Workaround**

With this I can still use Drush, and I don't need to modify the Drush source code, just add a conditional to each `settings.php`:

```
if (defined('DRUSH_VERSION')) {
    // Drush doesn't construct prefixes correctly, remove and use single DB
        // remember to call Drush with correct --uri= value!
    $db_prefixes = [];
} else {
    $db_prefixes = // whatever they usually are
}

$databases = [
...

unset($db_prefixes);
```

We use the Drush constant to detect if Drush is running or it's a webpage.  Doing it this way, rather than, for example, checking for the presence of  $_SERVER variables, also ensures things work properly if Drupal code is executed from the command line in other ways without Drush.

You then call Drush and user `--uri` to specify the appropriate settings.php:

```
drush up --uri=www.example.com/
drush up --uri=www.example.com/subsite
```

It's important to remember to use the correct site when you want to edit anything to do with users or roles (i.e. to ensure you're editing the correct set of MySQL tables).

See also:

- [GitHub issue - bootstrapping](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/2329)
- [GitHub issue - Drush debugging](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/3560)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the output again, I notice that Drush reports that the site "default" is initialized. Could it be as simple as helping Drush to select the correct site using the URI option - ref http://docs.drush.org/en/8.x/usage/

Comment: No luck with --uri or --root; the 'Site URI' in drush status is updated, but that's about all. I did clone the Git repository and have a look at the source code in the 8.x branch, but I'm not sure of a simple way of debugging it..